# PHP Change background on Time

Tags: php, time

So, For school i have to make PHP show the time, And for example when it is 12:00 the background is a afternoon one, and on 02:00 it is a Night one. This is my code:

```
<body>

<?php

<div class="tijd">
date_default_timezone_set('GMT+1');
echo date('h:i');

$Tijd = date('h');


if ($Tijd > 12 || $Tijd <17') {
echo '<div class="Middag"> </div>'; 
} 


if ($Tijd > 12 || $Tijd <17') { 
echo '<div class="Avond"> </div>';
} 


if ($Tijd >= '22') {
echo '<div class="Nacht"> </div>'; 
} 


if ($Tijd >= '6') {
echo '<div class="Ochtend"> </div>'; 
} 

 echo('Dit is een test...')
?>

</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

But, What is not working here? On the webpage it shows the time correctly but it doesnt show the background. It is also not working while i do a background color or something so i know it is not only the background color. I tried also to make a background in PHP but i kind of failed at that.

Comment: your conditions overlap. e.g. if it's 23, then you output the `Natch` div, but you **ALSO** output the `Octend` class, because 23>6 is true as well. and your conditions for middag and avod are identical as well, so those get duplicated too. Oh, and the php code is full of syntax errors as well. you cannot have "raw" html inside php, and you're missing a `'`.

Comment: you have mismatched single quotes all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if`, `else if`:

```
if ($Tijd > 12 || $Tijd <17) {
    echo '<div class="Middag"> </div>'; 
} else if ($Tijd > 12 || $Tijd <17) { 
    echo '<div class="Avond"> </div>';
} else if ($Tijd >= 22) {
    echo '<div class="Nacht"> </div>'; 
} else if ($Tijd >= 6) {
    echo '<div class="Ochtend"> </div>'; 
}
```

Having said that, your first two test conditions are exactly the same, so you should look at that too

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment but its a bit long).

In addition to Marc B's comment, there's random quotes all over the place - don't quote numeric values when you're trying to do a numeric comparison. You're mixing HTML and PHP -

```
<?php

<div class="tijd">
```

This should be causing your code to throw big errors. If you're not seeing these errors then you need to investigate why.

And the way you are running multiple if statements is messy. You could use if...else if...else if ...else, but if you use a switch statement your code will be much clearer:

```
switch((integer)$Tijd) {
   case 13:
   case 14:
   case 15:
   case 16:
      echo '<div class="Middag"> </div>';
      break; 
   case 22:
   case 23:
      echo '<div class="Nacht"> </div>'; 
      break;
   default:
      echo '<div class="Avond"> </div>';
      break;
  }
```

As you can see - there are gaps here which are not described by your original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hour = date('H'); //H is for 24 hours interval
if ($hour > 4 && $hour < 6) {
    $class = 'earlier-morning';
} elseif ($hour >=6 && $hour <=11) {
    $class = 'morning';
} elseif ($hour >=11 && $hour < 15) {
    $class = 'midday';
} elseif($hour >= 15 && $hour < 19) {
    $class = 'day';
} elseif ($hour >= 19 && $hour < 22) {
    $class = 'evening';
//the only one case left -  hours between 22 and 4
} else {
    $class = 'night';
}

echo sprintf('<div class="%s"></div>', $class);
```

The trick here is `elseif`
So only ONE condition will always work here.

P.S. I believe that extra quotes in your example is a typo ;-)

Comment: there are a lot of similar answers
but please note that `h` for 12 hours interval. So you will need to use `H`